# R How to rollback 12 month for each month and summarise

Tags: r

Sample data at the bottom of the page.

My goal is following:

for each month look back last 12 months and filter the data based on it. For an example, if we pick 2017-11-01. Therefore 12 months back from it is 2016-12-01. So filter data from period 2016-12-01 to 2017-11-01
Within that 12 month period, count how many Unique ID are there for each Group
Repeat above for each month in the dataframe i.e go back 12 month for each month in the dataset and get the count of Unique ID for each Group
If successfully executed above points, I can plot line graph with date on x axis and count of Unique ID for each Group on y axis for each month.

My attempt:

```
foo %>%
filter(Date >= “2016-12-01” & Date <= “2017-11-01”) %>%
group_by(ID, Group) %>%
count() %>%
group_by(Group) %>%
count
```

Output:
Min 2
sport 6
Xox 41

Above output is for 2017-11-01. However, my goal is to repeat this process for each month and store it in a dataframe so that I can draw a line plot.

Any help from the community is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Here is my sample dataframe:

```
#>         ID       Date Group
#> 1   D_2313 2017-07-01   Xox
#> 2   D_2416 2017-07-01   Xox
#> 3    D_446 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 4   D_3466 2017-07-01   Xox
#> 5   D_1183 2017-01-01   Xox
#> 6   D_3751 2015-12-01   Xox
#> 7     D_76 2017-03-01 sport
#> 8    D_441 2015-10-01   Xox
#> 9   D_1417 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 10  D_2886 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 11  D_1027 2016-03-01   Xox
#> 12  D_1955 2016-05-01   Xox
#> 13  D_1227 2017-04-01   Xox
#> 14   D_371 2016-11-01   Xox
#> 15   D_293 2017-10-01 sport
#> 16  D_2712 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 17  D_1122 2016-06-01   Xox
#> 18   D_839 2015-11-01   Xox
#> 19    D_83 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 20  D_3286 2016-03-01   Xox
#> 21  D_1216 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 22  D_3182 2017-07-01   Xox
#> 23   D_376 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 24   D_946 2016-11-01   Xox
#> 25  D_2585 2017-06-01   Xox
#> 26   D_162 2017-03-01   Xox
#> 27  D_2485 2017-05-01   Min
#> 28  D_1994 2017-05-01 sport
#> 29   D_543 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 30  D_3338 2016-07-01   Xox
#> 31    D_72 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 32   D_840 2016-04-01   Xox
#> 33   D_331 2016-01-01   Xox
#> 34  D_2644 2017-11-01   Xox
#> 35  D_2884 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 36  D_2626 2017-03-01   Xox
#> 37  D_2937 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 38  D_2818 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 39  D_3636 2017-10-01   Xox
#> 40  D_1103 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 41  D_1922 2015-11-01   Xox
#> 42  D_1088 2017-05-01   Xox
#> 43  D_3460 2016-09-01   Xox
#> 44  D_1465 2016-07-01   Xox
#> 45  D_1974 2016-06-01   Xox
#> 46  D_3525 2015-10-01   Xox
#> 47  D_2650 2017-04-01 sport
#> 48  D_2691 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 49  D_3616 2017-03-01   Xox
#> 50  D_1104 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 51  D_1533 2017-10-01   Xox
#> 52  D_3431 2016-06-01   Xox
#> 53  D_3458 2016-09-01   Xox
#> 54  D_1632 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 55   D_687 2017-01-01   Xox
#> 56  D_2560 2016-03-01   Xox
#> 57  D_1545 2016-03-01   Xox
#> 58  D_3073 2016-02-01   Xox
#> 59   D_468 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 60  D_2891 2015-12-01   Xox
#> 61  D_2479 2016-05-01   Xox
#> 62   D_254 2016-11-01   Xox
#> 63  D_2410 2017-10-01   Xox
#> 64  D_3633 2016-09-01   Xox
#> 65  D_2773 2017-05-01   Xox
#> 66   D_749 2016-09-01   Xox
#> 67  D_3259 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 68   D_143 2015-11-01   Xox
#> 69  D_3272 2016-01-01   Xox
#> 70   D_545 2016-05-01   Xox
#> 71  D_1684 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 72   D_341 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 73  D_3351 2016-12-01   Xox
#> 74  D_2127 2016-04-01   Xox
#> 75  D_1364 2016-03-01   Xox
#> 76  D_3500 2017-06-01   Xox
#> 77  D_2290 2016-12-01 sport
#> 78  D_2847 2015-11-01   Xox
#> 79   D_724 2017-09-01   Xox
#> 80  D_2111 2017-02-01   Xox
#> 81  D_2225 2017-06-01   Xox
#> 82   D_720 2016-01-01   Xox
#> 83  D_2709 2016-06-01   Xox
#> 84  D_1648 2015-12-01   Xox
#> 85  D_3251 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 86   D_184 2017-06-01   Xox
#> 87   D_961 2016-07-01   Xox
#> 88  D_2671 2016-08-01   Xox
#> 89  D_3217 2017-05-01   Xox
#> 90  D_1077 2016-04-01   Xox
#> 91  D_1290 2016-05-01 sport
#> 92  D_3637 2017-08-01   Xox
#> 93   D_436 2016-10-01   Xox
#> 94  D_3819 2017-08-01 sport
#> 95    D_25 2015-10-01   Xox
#> 96   D_739 2017-05-01   Min
#> 97  D_3697 2016-08-01   Xox
#> 98  D_1851 2016-11-01   Xox
#> 99    D_50 2016-07-01   Xox
#> 100 D_1286 2016-02-01   Xox
```

For complete data just in case months not enough to go back 12 months: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xslrswrys0hkl32/foo_complete.csv?dl=0

Comment: Maybe you should accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem so that the question can be considered closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define, using magrittr notation, a function `count_ids` which takes a vector of comma separated IDs and outputs the number of unique IDs.

Then convert that to a wide zoo object with one column per group aggregating at the same time so that all IDs in a particular Date/Group are concatenated using `toString`.  Run `rollapply` on it to count the unique IDs in the last 12 months.

Finally convert the data back to a long form data frame.

Note that `read.zoo` will fill in any missing year/month count with `NA` as long as there is no year/month that is missing from every group.  The data shown has no year/month that is missing from every group and, in fact, has almost no missing values at all, so it should work.  (Uncomment the first line to install
the development version of zoo -- this is needed here.)

```
# install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

# . is a vector of comma-separated strings of IDs
count_ids <- . %>%
    textConnection %>%
    scan(what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE) %>%
    unique %>%
    length

foo <- read.csv("foo_complete.csv")
foo %>%
    read.zoo(index = "Date", split = "Group", aggregate = toString) %>%
    rollapplyr(12, count_ids) %>%
    fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE, names = c("Date", "Group", "Count"))
```

If a wide zoo object were OK as output (see output further down below) then we could omit the last line.

#### zoo only

If we wished to express the above without magrittr we could write:

```
library(zoo)

count_ids <- function(x) {
    s <- scan(textConnection(x), what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
    length(unique(s))
}

foo <- read.csv("foo_complete.csv")
z <- read.zoo(foo, index = "Date", split = "Group", aggregate = toString)
z.roll <- rollapplyr(z, 12, count_ids)
fortify.zoo(z.roll, melt = TRUE, names = c("Date", "Group", "Count"))
```

#### rollapplyr output

The output of the `rollapplyr` line is as follows (the output of the final line would be too long to show):

```
> foo <- read.csv("foo_complete.csv")
> foo %>%
+     read.zoo(index = "Date", split = "Group", aggregate = toString) %>%
+     rollapplyr(12, count_ids) 
           Min sport  Xox
2016-07-01  17   137 2165
2016-08-01  17   142 2273
2016-09-01  19   149 2361
2016-10-01  19   154 2429
2016-11-01  21   156 2532
2016-12-01  22   161 2578
2017-01-01  22   163 2585
2017-02-01  25   163 2594
2017-03-01  25   167 2632
2017-04-01  25   168 2648
2017-05-01  26   166 2659
2017-06-01  23   166 2686
2017-07-01  24   162 2740
2017-08-01  27   163 2758
2017-09-01  28   162 2788
2017-10-01  28   165 2831
2017-11-01  28   158 2786
2017-12-01  29   153 2688
```

#### Updates

- now requires development version of zoo
- fixed situation where ID appears in multiple months
- incorporated the `summarize` statement into `read.zoo` aggregate argument so that it now uses magrittr and zoo
- add right alignment in `rollapply`
- show output from `rollapplyr`

Comment: I received following error message when reading

foo %>%
    group_by(Date, Group) %>%
    summarize(Count = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    read.zoo(split = "Group")

Error in read.zoo(., split = "Group") : index does not match data

Comment: I receive this error: Error in read.zoo(., split = "Group") : index has bad entry at data row 1

This may be related to read.zoo(split = "Group")  since all other above it works. I am not familiar with zoo. I am using R version 3.4.2

Comment: After updating my zoo through your link I ran recent codes of yours. My manual output is different from yours and also your output doesn't have full months. Using my attempt code on full dataset of foo I receive Group Xox count as 2786, sport as 158 and Min as 28 for the month of 2017-11-01. But your don't have that month and I can see these count matches for month 2017-05-01 on your output. The Count value should be assigned for the start of the month going backward in my case  the start date was 2017-11-01 going backward 12 months i.e. 2016-12-01, result should be assigned to 2017-11-01

Comment: Have changed `rollapply` to `rollapplyr` which gives right alignment rather than centered alignment.  Instead of taking 12 months centered around each date it now takes 12 months ending at each date.  Note that it only gives output for months for which there are 12 months ending in that date available but if you want partial months for those at the beginning you could add `partial = TRUE` argument to `rollapplyr`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to lubridate package to handle the Dates better.
I modified your filter clause and added two for loops, guessing that your first date is the 1.1.2015. The rest is just your example code.

```
library(lubridate)
result_list <- list()
for(y in 2015:2017){
  for(m in 1:12){
    d <- as.Date(paste0(y,"-",m, '-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    d2 <-  d %m-% months(12)
    result_list[[paste0(y,'_',m)]] <- foo %>%
      filter(Date >= d2 & Date < d) %>%
      group_by(ID, Group) %>%
      count() %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      count

  }
}
```

I put the result into a list. Maybe you have to modify that to plot the results easier.

Comment: How do I convert list to dataframe and still have Group column and the date of each month?